# Facebook Like-box: show more without clicking

Tags: facebook, facebook-likebox, facebook-timeline

Is there any way possible to make the Facebook Like-box show the timeline feed WITHOUT having the user press the "show more" button? Is there a different tool I could be using to achieve this?